# How to copy all text file from document directory in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsfilemanager

I need to Copy all text files (.txt) from document directory into my folder name "Text".

I can copy only one files.

I want to copy like `(*.txt)` with one touch.

Here codes is my single file copy.

```
self.fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *cutExtension = [tblGetNameToMove.textLabel.text stringByDeletingPathExtension];

NSString *txtPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt",cutExtension]];

NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Text/%@.txt",documentsDirectory,cutExtension];

[self.fileManager copyItemAtPath:txtPath toPath:fileName error:&error];
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Show your code which copies one file.

Comment: edited my question with my codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all the contents in the folder

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:documentsDirectory];
```

Enumerate over the files list and check if it constains .txt

```
[fileList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *string, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

  if ([string hasSuffix:@".txt"]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:strdestination toPath:toPath error:&Error];
  }
}];
```

**Update**

Updated my answer according to comments by Martin R

**Update 2**

As pointed out by Hot Licks use

```
if ([[string pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"txt"]) {
```

To check for the file extension.

Comment: I would use `if ([string pathExtension] == @"txt") { ...`

Comment: `[fileName hasSuffix:@"txt"]` is the correct way to check for a suffix.

Comment: @IanL: Never compare NSString's with "==" !!

Comment: strdestination is String?

Comment: lol - good point Martin! Brain freeze moment!! Never type comments without thinking ;)

Comment: Run the code and NSLog("%@", string); to see what it is. In your question you posted code about paths I am sure you can figure out how to construct them correctly for the destination and source.

Comment: NSUInteger index return only 0 and it doesn't work if condition.

Comment: I just updated my answer again to use the correct documents directory. Check that there are actually paths in that file array.

Comment: It's better to use `pathExtension` vs `hasSuffix`.  And if using `hasSuffix` be sure to include the `.`, otherwise you'll match "dataContxt".